# spawn new process in Azure from web application

Tags: asp.net, azure, process

Is it possible to run a new .net process from web application in Azure? Does it restrict it? 
I know about worker roles, but it's not the same.
i have checked Azure documenation, and coulnd't find such information..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worker Roles and Web Roles are just managed virtual machines that run code in your deployment package. You can absolutely spawn processes, along with just about anything else you'd want to do in a virtual machine. Just note that whenever a new instance of your role comes up, the OS starts from a "clean" state. Same thing when a role instance has to be respawned due to some type of failure. Meaning: Your startup tasks / `OnStart()` need to take care of re-initializing registry, running installers (if necessary) and then spawning your processes.

With Virtual Machines, you would set things up one time, since each VM is *stateful*.